# Determining Kc for the equilibrium involving iron thiocyanate using spectrophotometric data

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium, aqueous-solution, kinetics, spectrophotometry

> $$\ce{Fe^3+(aq) + SCN-(aq) <=> [Fe(SCN)]^2+(aq)}$$
>
> $\pu{12.0 mL}$ of $\pu{0.00110 mol L-1}$ $\ce{Fe^3+}$ was added to $\pu{6.00 mL}$ of $\pu{0.00140 mol L-1}$ $\ce{SCN-}$. The absorbance of the resulting solution was $0.625$. If the constant $(\varepsilon b) = \pu{3800 (mol L-1)-1}$, determine the value of $K_c$ that should be reported for the equilibrium.
>
> **a**. $\pu{1.64e-4}$
> **b**. $\pu{3.03e-4}$
> **c**. $\pu{4.67e-4}$
> **d**. $\pu{5.69e-4}$
> **e**. $957$

Answer given: **e**.

Given what I know about $K_c$ it should be:

$$K_c = \frac{\left[\ce{[Fe(SCN)]^2+}\right]}{[\ce{Fe^3+}][\ce{SCN-}]}$$

which gives me the answer **a**. I tried calculating $C$ by manipulating Beer's law, but I still don't end up with $957$ no matter what I try.

I would appreciate it if someone could walk me through the steps of solving this problem.

Comment: answer choice e is just 957? Without even going through the question, it seems like it would be noticeable that this option is several orders of magnitude larger than any of the other options and is also the only option greater than 1.

Comment: I noticed that and on the test I would pick e, I just don't understand how to actually arrive at that answer through calculations. I would like to understand it because I feel like the question won't be so straight forward on the real exam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, its often helpful to make an ICE table when dealing with problems of chemical equilibrium.
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\hline
 & \ce{Fe^3+} & \ce{SCN-} & \ce{[Fe(SCN)]^2+} \\ \hline
\mathrm{initial} & 1.32\times10^{-5} & 8.40\times10^{-6} & 0\\
\mathrm{change} & -x & -x &+x \\
 \mathrm{equil} & 1.32\times10^{-5}-x & 8.40\times10^{-6}-x & x\\ \hline\\
\mathrm{conc.} & \frac{1.32\times10^{-5}-x}{V}& \frac{8.40\times10^{-6}-x}{V} & \frac{x}{V}\end{array} \end{array}$$

Then we can use Beer's Law to find x.
$$\frac{x}{V}=\frac{A}{\epsilon b}=\pu{1.645\times10^{-3}mol/L} \to x= (1.645\times10^{-3})(.018)=\pu{2.961\times10^{-6}mol}$$

With x, we can find all the concentrations:

$[\ce{Fe^{3+}}]=5.69\times10^{-3}$

$[\ce{SCN-}]=3.02\times10^{-4}$

$[\ce{[Fe(SCN)]^2+}]=1.64\times10^{-4}$

Finally, we can then compute $K_c$:
$$K_c=\frac{[\ce{[Fe(SCN)]^2+}]}{[\ce{Fe^3+}][\ce{SCN-}]}=956.77$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't finding the concentrations properly and instead I was using the initial concentrations instead of the equilibrium ones. Very informative answer.

Comment: @Codeblockz definitely look at MaxW's answer as well. It can help with understanding a problem to see slightly different ways of getting to the solution.

Comment: Wonder when ICE tables became the rage. I don't ever remember seeing one before I came onto this site. -- When I was in chemistry classes there were just four elements, earth, air, water and fire. ;-)

Comment: @MaxW Thats an interesting point. It was what I was taught back in high school, so its at least been around for the last decade or so. However, I couldn't find the original source of the idea. Might be a worthwhile question here or History of Science and Math depending on if they allow pedagogical history.

Comment: I left high school in 1969.

Comment: @MaxW: It has been around for a while. But then, it wasn't called ICE. It's a cool name though! :-)

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Do you have a sense of when it was made or previous terminology used to describe it? I have opened a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/111978/41556) looking for when the method was made.

Comment: @Tyberius: Wasn't sure when is it introduced. But, I came to USA as a graduate student in 1989 (to Marquette University, Milwaukee, WI) and they were using the method then in Gen Chem classes (30 years ago! :-)).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is a bit strange since the details of the absorbance measurement aren't detailed very well. I'll assume the book defines the relationship as:
$$A = \epsilon bc$$

where:

- A=absorbance
- $\epsilon$ = molar attenuation coefficient
- $b$ = path length
- $c$ = concentration

So the concentration, c, of the $\ce{[Fe(SCN)]^2+}$ is:

$$ c = \dfrac{A}{\epsilon b} = \dfrac{0.625}{3800} = 1.64\times10^{-4}$$

Considering the dilutions...

$\ce{[Fe^{+3}] + [Fe(SCN)]^2+} = 0.00110 \times \dfrac{12}{18} = 7.33\times10^{-4}$

$\ce{[SCN^-] + [Fe(SCN)]^2+} = 0.00140 \times \dfrac{6}{18} = 4.67\times10^{-4}$

But there is $1.64\times10^{-4}$ of $\ce{[Fe(SCN)]^2+}$ so:

$\ce{[Fe^{+3}]} = 7.33\times10^{-4} - 1.64\times10^{-4} = 5.69\times10^{-4}$

$\ce{[SCN^-]} = 4.67\times10^{-4} - 1.64\times10^{-4} = 3.03\times10^{-4}$

Therefore:

$K_c = \dfrac{1.64\times10^{-4}}{(5.69\times10^{-4})(3.03\times10^{-4})} = 951$

*I'd assume the small difference is just due to a difference in rounding somewhere...*

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne - Made the correction. Thanks for pointing out the error.